# Ubuntu Font for Arabic and Urdu

Tags: ubuntu-font-family

I have been following Ubuntu's design and my interest is Ubuntu's font. The webpage, http://font.ubuntu.com/ , seems to be dead and there isn't any progress.

Is the Ubuntu Font for Arabic and Urdu dead?

Comment: Do you also want to know how to add these fonts to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Mitch No im just interested in their progress

Comment: Honestly, it’s shameful how Canonical’s stakeholders have let this project die with their gross mismanagement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, progress has stalled.

Paul Sladen has summed it up nicely, so I’ll just [quote](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+question/231422) him:

> Quite a lot of this is hinging (waiting) on me. Dalton Maag are based in London, and when I was working at Canonical it was easy to pop in once a week or so, however I have been in London a lot less since over the last year.
>
> I need to work on and complete some other things, and then afterwards to arrange to spend at least a couple of weeks in London working with Dalton Maag on this project.
>
> Effectively, it's stacked up.

Update (Jan 2016): A new release of the Ubuntu Font Family containing Arabic/Urdu and Hebrew script support is available. See [Paul’s comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298600/ubuntu-font-for-arabic-and-urdu/328472#comment1063773_361450) below, and the announcement I made last year in [my blog](https://fitoschido.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/ubuntu-font-family-0-84-arabic-hebrew-testing-xenial/).

Comment: Hmmm sad to know :-(

Answer (score 2):

Muhammad Ahmad Zafar: To update you (as of October 2013).  I have some newer snapshots from Dalton Maag with greater Arabic script coverage for the main font weights in the Ubuntu Font Family.  There are still some issues with these (eg. baseline alignment).  Would you be willing to help test them at some point during the next month?  This is Arabic ''script'' (Urdu/Farsi/… and not purely Arabic).

Comment: By testing you mean I will have to use the font and report issues?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea!  This means we can catch anything obvious earlier.

Comment: Yes I am willing

Comment: any update? i am still waiting and now its over a year also.

Comment: A dead project of Ubuntu?

Comment: @M.AhmadZafar: Have been able to test the latest Arabic Beta metrics package in Xenial?  This was unploaded to the testing archive in November 2015, about three weeks before the comment above so I don't know if you've seen it (or perhaps had been testing it all along without realising it!
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/ubuntu-font-family-sources