# Ubuntu Arabic font family

Tags: fonts, beta, arabic

Why are the Ubuntu font developers taking too long to finalize the Arabian font family?
And what happened to the beta Arabic font? why isn't it supported anymore?
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

See [this support request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79012/how-can-i-install-a-complete-arabic-font) and [this inquiry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298600/ubuntu-font-for-arabic-and-urdu). It seems like you can get an Arabic font working by installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package, which provides `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, which in turn includes the font from Microsoft. It is not clear whether this font is 100% functional, but one person at least reported that it was working for them.

Comment: I'm not talking about any Arabic font, I'm talking about the Ubuntu Arabic Font Family itself.

Comment: Ubuntu is developing an Arabic font of its own font font.ubuntu.com and still beta since three year and I think Abood asks about that and not a general Arabic font

Comment: This is not answer to the question, there was a "Ubuntu Arabic font family" see http://design.canonical.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Ubuntu-Arabic.pdf http://design.canonical.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/ubuntu-arabic-now-with-horizontal-dots.pdf http://design.canonical.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/cordale-arabic-beta-540x148.png